# No Prisoner Release Money

Tags: prison-architect

I have a prison with a couple hundred Prisoners, so every hour or so one is Released. The way I see it, as soon as they exit the map, you get a `$3,000 Prisoner Release Reward`. This happens most of the time with my Prisoners, but every now and then, on will exit the map as usual, but I don't get any money! Is this normal?

**Am I supposed to get money with every Prisoner Release?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you only get the $3,000 if the prisoner doesn't re-offend.

A prisoner's re-offending chance is calculated based on several factors, both from their prison experience and their history. When a prisoner is released, whether through successful parole or their sentence ending, this chance is checked immediately. If the prisoner doesn't reoffend, you receive a $3,000 bonus.

If the prisoner does reoffend, there is no bonus. There is no penalty for this if their sentence was over but you can be warned/fired if too many paroled prisoners reoffend.

Comment: In addition to the problems you describe if too many paroled prisoners reoffend, I believe you are also fined something like $1000.